# How to select date range in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am doing c# programming , Kind of automation work. It involves generation of a report in one of our internal server. We have been provided one admin api to create report in that server(server has report/logs functionality) . Currently we are using that api to create report and retrieve report data on daily basis.

Now we want to generate the report according to date range, For ex: Report should generate with last 3 days including today's data. (Even though it is generating today).

Is there any option in c# to select date range, I just want to store the date range in a variable and generate the report with 3 days data. This is my plan

Comment: A class with `DateTime StartDate` and `DateTime EndDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have a StartDate DateTime and EndDate DateTime property for the api. Then use that as range.

Else if your EndDate is fixed to today, then you can add an property NoOfDays int 
Then you can use, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).